# Which namespace on assign operation in bpel to use - selectionFailure, no results for expression

Tags: namespaces, wso2, bpel

The situation is that I have a fairly simple BPEL process that invokes a service. I want to access the response message elements and assign then to another service (or even to the result of the BPEL process itself to return to the client). The issue I am having is that the imported wsdl for the service to invoke has a namespace declaration in it e.g. ldap and all the imported xsd elements for that wsdl also have the same ldap namespace declared.

```
<definitions
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ldap="http://webservices.hrldaplookup.ecis.police.uk/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    targetNamespace="http://webservices.hrldaplookup.ecis.police.uk/" name="LDAPLookupServiceImpl">
```

This is then imported into my BPEL process, again using the ldap namespace.

```
 <bpel:process name="HRLDAPProces"
         targetNamespace="http://ldap.ecis.police.uk/Person/process"
         suppressJoinFailure="yes"
         xmlns:tns="http://ldap.ecis.police.uk/Person/process"
         xmlns:bpel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable"
         xmlns:ldap="http://webservices.hrldaplookup.ecis.police.uk/"  xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns0="http://uk.police.ecis.police.uk/athena/services/ConstrainedValueService" xmlns:ns="http://webservices.cvmanagement.athena.ecis.police.uk/">

    <!-- Import the client WSDL -->
    <bpel:import namespace="http://webservices.cvmanagement.athena.ecis.police.uk/" location="ConstrainedValueService.wsdl" importType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"></bpel:import>
    <bpel:import namespace="http://uk.police.ecis.police.uk/athena/services/ConstrainedValueService" location="ConstrainedValueService_1.wsdl" importType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"></bpel:import>
    <bpel:import namespace="http://webservices.hrldaplookup.ecis.police.uk/" location="LDAPLookupServiceImpl.wsdl" importType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"></bpel:import>
    <bpel:import location="HRLDAPProcesArtifacts.wsdl" namespace="http://ldap.ecis.police.uk/Person/process" 
            importType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
```

When the service is invoked the response message has its own arbitrary namespaces assigned to the elements.

```
<getPersonnelResponse xmlns="http://webservices.hrldaplookup.ecis.police.uk/" xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="http://webservices.hrldaplookup.ecis.police.uk/" xmlns:ns3="http://ldap.ecis.police.uk/Person" xmlns:ns4="http://ecis.police.uk/ldaplookupservice"><personnelData xmlns="http://ecis.police.uk/ldaplookupservice"><detail xmlns="http://ldap.ecis.police.uk/Person">
```

When I want to assign variable parameter parts to something else I don't know which namespace to use.

```
$LDAPLookupResponse.parameters/ldap:personnelData/ldap:detail/item[1]
```

or

```
$LDAPLookupResponse.parameters/ns2:personnelData/ns4:detail/ns4:item[1]
```

Neither seem to work.

I'm sure I am just missing something simple, I just need pointing in the right direction.

Thanks

I'm using WSO2 Business Process server.

Full bpel process is [here](http://pastebin.com/Gy9REF1t) as requested by Thilini Ishaka - thanks!

and the log file for the error is

```
TID: [0] [BPS] [2013-01-21 16:22:47,750] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.messagetrace} -  Service invocation completed: MEXId: hqejbhcnphr7xlanvn6p6t :: {http://webservices.hrldaplookup.ecis.police.uk/}LDAPLookupServiceImpl.getPersonnel {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.messagetrace}
TID: [0] [BPS] [2013-01-21 16:22:47,750] TRACE {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.messagetrace} -  Response message: MEXId: hqejbhcnphr7xlanvn6p6t :: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:getPersonnelResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webservices.hrldaplookup.ecis.police.uk/" xmlns:ns4="http://ecis.police.uk/ldaplookupservice" xmlns:ns3="http://ldap.ecis.police.uk/Person"><ns4:personnelData><ns3:detail><ns3:item title="Managers Name">Bob NELSON PSE 56619</ns3:item><ns3:item title="Fullname">Conrad CRAMPTON PSE 52704</ns3:item><ns3:item title="Rank">PSE</ns3:item><ns3:item title="Collar Number">46052704</ns3:item><ns3:item title="Location">Headquarters</ns3:item><ns3:item title="Email address">conrad.crampton@kent.pnn.police.uk</ns3:item><ns3:item title="Last Name">Crampton</ns3:item><ns3:item title="Force Number">52704</ns3:item><ns3:item title="Managers Force Number">56619</ns3:item><ns3:item title="First Name">Conrad</ns3:item></ns3:detail></ns4:personnelData></ns2:getPersonnelResponse></S:Body></S:Envelope> {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.messagetrace}
TID: [0] [BPS] [2013-01-21 16:22:47,750]  INFO {org.apache.ode.bpel.runtime.ASSIGN} -  Assignment Fault: {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure,lineNo=322,faultExplanation={http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure: R-Value expression "{OXPath10Expression $LDAPLookupResponse.parameters//ldap:item[@title = 'Rank']}" did not select any nodes. {org.apache.ode.bpel.runtime.ASSIGN}
TID: [0] [BPS] [2013-01-21 16:22:47,750]  INFO {org.apache.ode.bpel.runtime.ASSIGN} -  Assignment Fault: {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure,lineNo=322,faultExplanation={http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure: R-Value expression "{OXPath10Expression $LDAPLookupResponse.parameters//ldap:item[@title = 'Rank']}" did not select any nodes. {org.apache.ode.bpel.runtime.ASSIGN}
TID: [0] [BPS] [2013-01-21 16:22:47,765]  WARN {org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess} -  Instance 3652 of {http://ldap.ecis.police.uk/Person/process}HRLDAPProces-31 has completed with fault: FaultData: [faultName={http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure, faulType=null ({http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure: R-Value expression "{OXPath10Expression $LDAPLookupResponse.parameters//ldap:item[@title = 'Rank']}" did not select any nodes.)] @322 {org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess}
TID: [0] [BPS] [2013-01-21 16:22:47,765]  WARN {org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess} -  Instance 3652 of {http://ldap.ecis.police.uk/Person/process}HRLDAPProces-31 has completed with fault: FaultData: [faultName={http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure, faulType=null ({http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure: R-Value expression "{OXPath10Expression $LDAPLookupResponse.parameters//ldap:item[@title = 'Rank']}" did not select any nodes.)] @322 {org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess}
TID: [0] [BPS] [2013-01-21 16:22:47,859] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.messagetrace} -  Reply Sent: HRLDAPProces.{http://ldap.ecis.police.uk/Person/process}process {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.messagetrace}
TID: [0] [BPS] [2013-01-21 16:22:47,859] TRACE {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.messagetrace} -  Response message: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsa:Action>http://ldap.ecis.police.uk/Person/process/HRLDAPProces/processResponse</wsa:Action><wsa:RelatesTo>http://identifiers.wso2.com/messageid/1358785364081/1999227541</wsa:RelatesTo></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode><faultstring xmlns:axis2ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable">axis2ns2:selectionFailure</faultstring><detail/></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.messagetrace}
TID: [0] [BPS] [2013-01-21 16:23:17,875]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2013-01-21 16:23:17,875+0000] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be a namespace conflict in your process file. 
Ideally it should work with;

$LDAPLookupResponse.parameters/ldap:personnelData/ldap:detail/item[1]

Can you please post the full bpel config and the full error log to check whether any namespace conflicts in the configuration.

Comment: Hi, I've edited original post with details requested. Have you any more advice you can give with this extra detail?

Comment: Pls check line 355, $LDAPLookupResponse.parameters//item[1], in the config. Issue seems to be in this line.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, but this line is as a result of the number of different attempts at getting this to work (with the problem I was having with namespaces).
I think your initial suggestion around namespace conflicts is the problem. I since have started from scratch and now got it working in the way I had anticipated (as per tutorials, documentation etc.) I don't know what the specific issue was but clearly to do with namespaces, just unfortunately using a GUI editor (within Eclipse) doesn't help when things go wrong.
Thanks for looking though - I will revisit this to understand better